# Mobile Apps - Backend Service calls

Tags: android, mobile

Am not familiar with the mobile app development..

I had a query that was posed to me...How do mobile apps communicate with the

backend services/systems

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Usually, mobile devices communicate with Servers using HTTP Requests, depends on the type of the request you need (GET/POST/PUT etc.), meaning that you connect to the Servers by a base URL and added parameters you need/want.

example: "http://your_base_url/your_function_to_call/your_parameters..."

The returned data is usually in JSON or XML format.

Typically those calls are relying on AccessToken or another parameter for identifying the user.

Another way is to register to Push Services and get data from Server whenever the Server decides. In Android it is called GCM (Google Cloud Messaging).

It is really not a issue to write about in a few sentences but this is in general.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but are there any tools to generate the access token or is it something thats done programmatically ?